# Connect OBS studio to android emulator

Tags: android

Hi I just beginner to use this apps, I would like to make OBS virtual camera on android emulator but I dont know how,does anyone know how to do it?

I try to connect but the apps just keep closing and sometimes just freeze
and how do you using the virtual camera

Comment: It would help to understand what PC OS (Linux/Mac/Windows) version, PC RAM size, CPU/GPU you are running. Do realize that the [Android emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#requirements) and OBS take up a lot of resources.